# How to generate random numbers at set time intervals?

Tags: java, random, timer

I have developed code in Java for generating ten random numbers from a range 0 to 99.  The problem is I need to generate a random number for every 2 min.  I am new to this area and need your views.

Answer (score 7):

This example adds a random number to a blocking dequeue every two minutes. You can take the numbers from the queue when you need them. You can use java.util.Timer as a lightweight facility to schedule the number generation or you can use java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService for a more versatile solution if you need more sophistication in the future. By writing the numbers to a dequeue, you have a unified interface of retrieving numbers from both facilities.

First, we set up the blocking queue:

```
final BlockingDequeue<Integer> queue = new LinkedBlockingDequeue<Integer>();
```

Here is the setup with java.utilTimer:

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        queue.put(Math.round(Math.random() * 99));
        // or use whatever method you chose to generate the number...
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(true)Timer();
timer.schedule(task, 0, 120000);
```

This is the setup with java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        queue.put(Math.round(Math.random() * 99));
        // or use whatever method you chose to generate the number...
    }
};
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 120, SECONDS);
```

Now, you can get a new random number from the queue every two minutes. The queue will block until a new number becomes available...

```
int numbers = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
    Inetger rand = queue.remove();
    System.out.println("new random number: " + rand);
}
```

Once you are done, you can terminate the scheduler. If you used the Timer, just do

```
timer.cancel();
```

If you used ScheduledExecutorService you can do

```
scheduler.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two requirements which are unrelated:

1. Generate random numbers
2. Perform the task every 2 minutes.

To do anything every 2 minutes you can use a ScheduledExecutorService.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule your program to be run once every two minutes using whatever scheduling features are available to you in your target environment (e.g., `cron`, `at`, Windows Scheduled Tasks, etc.).

Or you can use the [`Thread#sleep`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) method to suspend your application for 2,000ms and run your code in a loop:

```
while (loopCondition) {
    /* ...generate random number... */

    // Suspend execution for 2 minutes
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000 * 60 * 2);
}
```

(That's just example code, you'll need to handle the InterruptedException and such.)

Comment: Thats busy waiting and very inefficient.

Comment: @Willi: No, it isn't. That's the whole *point* of using `sleep`. And note that it's not my first suggestion.

Comment: Never said it is. And blocking the current thread is even not a solution to the problem. He wants a random number being generated every 2 seconds. What will be the point of blocking and waiting two seconds without doing anything? Using a ScheduledExecutorService would be the best solution here. Thread.sleep(..) almost never makes sense.

Comment: @Willi: You said it was "busy waiting." It isn't. It's thread suspension. All sorts of perfectly valid uses for it, including doing something every couple of seconds without introducing further dependencies. I think we're broadly in agreement, though, that it's not the first choice.

Comment: If you don't need to do anything else while waiting for the next number to be generated, this is the simplest solution. And no, it's not busy waiting.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerExample {
    Random rand = new Random();
    static int currRand;

    TimerExample() {
        currRand = rand.nextInt(99);
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                currRand = rand.nextInt(99);
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, actionListener);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        TimerExample te = new TimerExample();
        while( true ) {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
            System.out.println("current value:" + currRand );
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Of course you should set 2000 in  new Timer(2000, actionListener); to 120 000 for two minutes.

Comment: Introducing a dependency on Swing seems a bit of overkill for this sort of problem.

Comment: Of course java.util.TimerTask and Timer could also be used. I just extended an existing example...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the problem. If you wish to generate a different random number every two minutes, simply call your `rnd` function every two minutes.

This could be as simple as something like (pseudo-code):

```
n = rnd()
repeat until finished:
    use n for something
    sleep for two minutes
    n = rnd()
```

If you want to keep using the same random number for two minutes and generate a new one:

```
time t = 0
int n = 0

def sort_of_rnd():
    if now() - t > two minutes:
        n = rnd()
        t = now()
    return n
```

which will continue to return the *same* number for a two minute period.

Comment: @Aravindkumar: Please edit your own question and put the code there.

Comment: Thats busy waiting, dont do that.

Comment: No, it's not necessarily busy waiting. Busy waiting occurs when you repeatedly check for a predicate without knowing whether it will hold or not. In this case, the predicate is determined by the wait-time and you know the predicate holds once you waited for two minutes. Thus this doesn't qualify as busy waiting/spinning in my opinion.