# java.util.Timer: Is it deprecated?

Tags: java, timer

I read in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212848/how-to-genarate-random-numbers/2212887#2212887) and in many other questions about scheduling (sorry, no references) that `java.util.Timer` is deprecated. I really hope not since I'm using it as the light way to schedule things in Java (and it works nicely). But if it's deprecated, I'll look elsewhere. **However, a quick look at the [API docs for 1.6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) doesn't say anything about it being deprecated.** It's not even mentioned in Sun's [Deprecated List](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/deprecated-list.html).

**Is it officially deprecated<sup>*</sup> and if so, what should I use instead?**

---

<sup>*</sup> On the other hand, **if it's not deprecated,** could people stop badmouthing this innocent and brilliantly-implemented set-o-classes?

Comment: `java.util.Timer` is far from brilliantly written. It's inflexible and difficult to write testable code around. `ScheduledExecutorService` is better in every measurable way.

Comment: @skaffman, that may be correct. My only question is whether `ScheduledExecutorService` is as lightweight as `Timer`. It's just a thin wrapper on `Object.wait(long)`... what about Scheduled...?

Comment: The source code is there, have a look for yourself. What I can say is that the `java.util.concurrent` stuff (including `ScheduledExecutorService`) has been designed for extremely high throughput, which `Timer` never was.

Comment: Thank you @skaffman, I will check out he source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [[JDK-8154799] deprecate Timer and TimerTask](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154799) in the JDK’s bug tracker and in mid-2016 [JEP 277](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/277) stated that `java.util.Timer` (and `TimerTask`) would be deprecated in JDK 9.

> Several Java SE APIs will have a @Deprecated annotation added,
>   updated, or removed. Some examples of such changes are listed below.
>
> […]
>
> - add @Deprecated to `java.util.Timer` and `TimerTask`

However, in the JDK 9 release, those classes are not deprecated (deprecated classes can be found in the [Deprecated List](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/deprecated-list.html#class)).

Comment: Thanks. Readers should see the previously accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2213146/8047

Comment: @Martin: I didn't see any reference to Timer or TimerTask being deprecated, as of today (6/26/2017). Maybe they were removed from the list.

Comment: @FractalBob Indeed these classes do not appear in the [JDK9 Deprecated List](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/deprecated-list.html#class). I found [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154799)—looks like it’s not yet decided if they will be deprecated (see the change at 2016-10-04 21:40 under Activity → All).

Answer (score 17):

As others have mentioned, no it is not deprecated but I personally always use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead as it offers a richer API and more flexibility:

- `ScheduledExecutorService` allows you to specify the number of threads whereas `Timer` always uses a single thread.
- `ScheduledExecutorService` can be constructed with a [`ThreadFactory`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) allowing control over thread aspects other than the name / daemon status (e.g. priority, `ThreadGroup`, `UncaughtExceptionHandler`).
- `ScheduledExecutorService` allows tasks to be scheduled with fixed delay as well as at a fixed rate.
- `ScheduledExecutorService` accepts `Callable` / `Runnable` as it's unit of work, meaning that you don't need to subclass `TimerTask` specifically to use it; i.e. you could submit the same `Callable` implementation to a regular `ExecutorService` or a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: The last benefit might be interesting to me. But aside from that, I'm worried that ScheduledEx... might be "heavier". Thoughts?

Comment: Assuming you create a ScheduledExecutorService with a single thread it is highly unlikely you'll see any difference in performance (despite Timer containing its own priority queue implementation).

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a misunderstanding. The Timer class's JavaDoc mentions `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and notes, that this class is *effectively a more versatile replacement* for the Timer/TimerTask combination. Nothing else. Timer is not deprecated.

Another quote from JavaDoc, ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor this time:

> A ThreadPoolExecutor  that can additionally schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically. This class is preferable to Timer  when multiple worker threads are needed, or when the additional flexibility or capabilities of ThreadPoolExecutor  (which this class extends) are required.

Comment: Thanks for that. So do you think, in terms of weight of implementation -- speed, memory-use, CPU-use -- Timer is the lightest option?

Comment: Timer is 'lightweight' in that is only has a single background thread.  Be aware that both Timer and ScheduledExecutorService use an array internally to hold scheduled tasks.  Hence, scheduling 10,000,000 tasks and then cancelling them will leave the array size at 10,000,000.  In reality this would rarely be an issue.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know and don't care about performance in most cases. If I had a performance issue, than exchanging Timer.sleep() by ScheduledThreadPoolExecuter would be on of the last things I looked at...

Comment: Sorry @Andreas_D I don't normally care abut performance either, but I'm using Timer -- successfully -- to create MIDI-note loopers. So if there might easily be 1K scheduled tasks per second... on the other hand, maybe I've gone in an absolutely crazy direction by using Timers.

Answer (score 6):

No. Not all. You may want to use other mechanisms like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) for more complex timer requirements, but Timer works perfectly well and is not going anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll check out Quartz, too.

Comment: Yes, Quartz is excellent although the API is not so great.  However, the Quartz wrappers provided with Spring make it a lot more useable / flexible.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not deprecated.  In addition to Sun's [Deprecated List](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/deprecated-list.html), you'll also see a note in the JavaDoc for a class that has been deprecated.  For example, the note for [StringBufferInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html) says:

> Deprecated. This class does not properly convert characters into bytes. As of JDK 1.1, the preferred way to create a stream from a string is via the StringReader class.

Comment: Thanks Bill, the deprecated list was mentioned in the question. I was wondering if there was some insider knowledge that lets people know that Timer is deprecated (or something).

Comment: @yar: Oh, yes, I didn't notice that the word "here" was linked.  The JavaDoc for the `Timer` class itself will have a note that will let you know if it's ever deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I admit linking the word `here` is not best-practice for  anchor-text :)

Comment: @yar: I'm guilty of doing the same, so I can't complain too loudly. :)

Comment: we've all been `<a href='there'>there</a>`

Answer (score 2):

In jdk1.6_10 it's not deprecated, so there is no need for an alternative.

Comment: `java.util.Date` isn't deprecated either, but that's is very much in need of an alternative.

Comment: Same goes for Observer / Observable.

Comment: @skaffman what do you use instead of `java.util.Date`? And if they don't deprecate these things, how am I supposed to know not to use them?

Comment: @yar : You know not to use them when you realise they're rubbish. Use your judgement. The defacto replacement for `java.util.Date` is JodaTime.