# There is a way to make a timer that works when the Device is locked?

Tags: android, timer, wakelock

I'm searching a way to make a chronometer that every 5 seconds emits a sound.
The problem is that when the device is locked the timer obviously stops (because the CPU goes in sleep mode).

My code:

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         chronsound.start();//Emit the sound
         customHandler.postDelayed(this,5000);
    }
};
```

There is a way to do this WITHOUT using the WakeLock?
Thank you!

Comment: use a Service - for a timer I recommend an IntentService

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android timer that works when device is sleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918192/android-timer-that-works-when-device-is-sleeping)

Comment: Thank you, but the post you linked me doesn't solve my problem.