# onlongclicklistener and timer in android

Tags: java, android, timer, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I'm trying to  write an android game,

I want my person on the view would dance when I press.

and have a score keep gaining during the pressing.

how can i solve the score problem ?

Can timer help ?

And how's the difference between onlongclick and onclick ?

here is my code:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.text.Layout;

public class pi extends Activity {
     OnTouchListener listen1;  
     RelativeLayout f1;
     int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pi);
        listen1 = new OnTouchListener() {       
            private TextView txt;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                txt.setText("aaaaa");
                        return false;
            }


        };


        f1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.titlescreenframe);
        f1.setOnTouchListener(listen1);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_pi, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

onTouch is click and release.  onLongClick is click and hold until the onLongClick event fires.

To keep your score, override onTouch().  When a finger goes down, start an timer that starts to increase the score.  When the finger goes up.  Stop the task.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how) and [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/handle-touch-events-ontouchevent)