# Automatic dialog dismiss in Android

Tags: android, view, dialog, dismiss

I a'm creating an Android application in which I'm managing some remainders. I want that when a certain event occur the dialog is show, And this is not a problem from me. But I want that if the user does not make any response within two minutes the dialog automatically dismiss. How can I implement this?

Comment: write a thread probably which run for two minutes after the dailog is shown... and if the user didnt make any response use dismiss() to dismiss the dialog... before dismissing i think its better to check whether the dialog object is null or not. if its null i think u need not dismiss and if not dismiss it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static AlertDialog alert = ....;


alert.show();

Runnable dismissRunner = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if( alert != null )
            alert.dismiss();            
    };
new Handler().postDelayed( dismissRunner, 120000 );
```

Don't forget to `alert = null` in your regular dialog dismiss code (i.e. button onClick).

Answer (score 2):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.game_message);
        game_message = builder.create();
        game_message.show();


        final Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                game_message.dismiss(); // when the task active then close the dialog
                t.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread, otherwise, you may receive a crash report
            }
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: Try to add some description with your code. What your code does ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do just that using Timer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

[Android timer? How-to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how)

The stackoverflow link describes how to use it to run a reoccuring task, but you can use it to run a one-shot task as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
final Timer t = new Timer();
                t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        alert.dismiss(); 
                        t.cancel(); 
                    }
                }, 2000);
```