# Constantly update TextView with stopwatch value

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a very simple stopwatch widget in my Android activity such that the user can hit start/reset to start the timer, and stop to stop it. All of the functionality is there, but I can't seem to find a way to constantly display the value of this stopwatch.

I'm currently using a custom object that stores a `long` value representing the time the `Stopwatch` object was created, a constructor that sets this `long` value to the current time, and a `displayTime` method that returns the a `double` value representing the current time in seconds by subtracting the current time from the original time and divides by 1000.0.

Like I said, functionally it's flawless, but I can't see a way to constantly update a `TextView` object with the value of `displayTime()`. Can anyone suggest as simple of a solution as possible to accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: You need to use Timer class for this purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Reply as an answer so I can approve and upvote you.

Comment: @GuntherFox Less of a duplicate and more of a 'where do I start'. smit answered it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Timer class for this purpose.

```
ActionListener timerTask = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    lblTime.setText("Set your time here");     
        }
    };
Timer timer = new Timer(500, timerTask);
timer.start();
```

For Timer Class Information and API

1. [Class Timer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)
2. [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use a `Handler`.

```
private Handler h = new Handler();
private Runnable update = new Runnable() {
    void run() {
        // update the time in the text view here
        h.postDelayed(this, 1000); // reschedule the update in 1 sec
    }
};

// to start the update process
h.postDelayed(update, 0); // run the update the first time
```