# how to prevent the graph from overwriting the previous plot using achartengine

Tags: java, android, eclipse, achartengine

I have made the plot to repaint the graph from the first once it reaches end. Now my problem is the graph gets overwritten. The previous plot remains as such. So, how should i repaint after clearing the previous plot? And by clearing i should not loose the previous data. It should remain as such when i scroll.Can someone help me with this pls?

Comment: Which graph you are using, and also one more thing do you want to clear the graphics drawn over the canvas ?

Comment: Using Linegraph to plot ECG in real time. I want the graphplot similar to the one in this.                                         http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6BuRqeUhqc.

Comment: I do not understand much of your question. What means "it reaches end"? What means "gets overwritten"? What means "remains as such"? Why would you clear it without losing previous data?

Comment: sorry. I want my graph similar to the graph in the link I have mentioned in before comment. I am plotting a real time graph. When I receive data via bluetooth I add those data one by one to the graph, so that the graph plots dynamically by appending them to the right. Now, my graph keeps sliding at right as long as the data is available.  Instead I want it like when the graph reaches the end of the layout,I dont want it to keep on sliding right.but the cursor should be sent to front so that the graph is drawn from the initial position similar to an oscilloscope view. Pls see the video.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer the questions I understood:

- You can clear data from the previous series, by removing it
- You can control the visible area by using `renderer.setXAxisMin()` and `renderer.setXAxisMax()`
- When you want the cursor sent back to the beginning, you can create a new series and start adding data to this series
- You can hide the legend, if you don't need it by calling `renderer.setShowLegend(false)`

The changes will be visible on the screen after calling `chartView.repaint()`.