# Call method after 5 millisecond

Tags: android, delay, record, playing

How to call record method after 5 millisecond playing audio with MediaPlayer. I tried something like that but i don't know and i didn't find any good examples to end this.

```
while(mp.isPlaying()){
    if(record=0){
       for(int i=0; i<5millisec; i++){ //how to define 5 millisec or is any better solution
       }
    startRecord();
    record=1;
    }
}
mp.stop();
mp.release();
mp=null;
```

Comment: Would `Thread.sleep(5);` solve this problem?

Comment: u need to use timer schedule for this.-  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay?rq=1

Comment: @yuva Timer's resolution is probably more than 5 ms...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

5 milliseconds is a very short time period and you can't limit audio output to such duration.
you can use `Handler` to execute a delayed function but it will not ensure execution at 5 milliseconds after scheduling.
a code for doing that:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
@Override
      public void run(){
        startRecord();
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
   }
}, 5);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the method postDelayed. 
In the example below I run my routine 100 millis after to call the method.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        barVolume.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
                    }
                }, 
                100);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
//Auto Start after 2 seconds
        if(ENABLE_AUTO_START) {
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // this code will be executed after 2 seconds
                    doThis();
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to use [Thread.sleep](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)?

Like so:

```
if(record == 0){
   Thread.sleep(5);
}
```

Notice that I used `==` in the `if` statement to check for equality, rather than assigning the value of `0` each time, I assume this is what you want.

It is worth mentioning that putting a Thread to sleep will stop it doing anything for the duration that you specify. If this is a UI Thread, then you will effectively "freeze" the UI for that duration, so make sure you are using it appropriately. Hwoever, you example `for` loop indicates this is exactly the kind of thing you are attempting to do.

Comment: Just be wary that this fine on a spawned thread, but is a bad idea if you call it from the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Thread.sleep(5), or, if you don't want to use the UI thread for this, you could use a Timer, or an AsyncTask which triggers a callback after waiting 5ms in the doInBackground() method.

Here is a pretty good example for using Timer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4598737/832008

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Using an ExecutorService, you can schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically. The following example shows a class with a method that sets up a ScheduledExecutorService to beep every ten seconds for an hour:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void beepForAnHour() {
     final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
     };
     final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
     scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
     }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

public void startRecording(String fileName) {
    if(mRecorder != null) {
        try {
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(StartPhoneCallService.class.getSimpleName(), "prepare() failed");
            }
            mRecorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void stopRecording() {
    if(mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }
}
```

Now you can call the Handler to play 5 millisecond

```
private final int recording_time = 5;

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run() {
     startRecording("YOUR FILE NAME");
     // Stop your recording after 5 milliseconds
     stopRecording();
   }
}, recording_time );
```