# How to Display voice recorder (recording time with progress bar) in Android

Tags: android, audio

I am creating voice recording application.i done voice recording start and stop.but i want to update recording time,progress in activity.can u please suggest me which approach is good in android

Comment: Have a look on this http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/06/voice-recording-in-android.html

Comment: hi shruthi ,I was all ready done voice recording but i want to update recording time,progress when i recording audio.

Comment: Finding examples of how to update a text field periodically should be trivial. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how for example.

Comment: @Surya, how did you fix this? I tried a separate timer but the problem is that how do we keep Recording & the timer in sync?