# Java for Android timer

Tags: java, android, timer, clock

Can you tell me where is the problem on this line: `timerText.setText(seconds);`.

```
public class ShowTimer extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timer_test_xml);

        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            int seconds;
            TextView timerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimerTestId);
            @Override
            public void run() {
                seconds++;
                timerText.setText(seconds);
            }
        }, 0, 1000);

    }}
```

Comment: The `setText(int)` function on android has no documentation, so I really have no idea what it does. Are you sure its the function you want to be calling?

Comment: If we put a string as a parameter of the method still does not work :)

Comment: What is it that you want to happen and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is display `seconds` in the text view. However, the `TextView.setText(int)` function does not do this (Im not actually sure what it does). What you want to do is `timerText.setText(""+seconds);` to convert the parameter into a string and change the function call to a different overloaded function.

Answer (score 0):

`seconds` is an `int`, whereas I think you want to be passing as character sequence, or a reference to one via a resource id, [as per the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

Though this doesn't answer the OP's original question, there are alternative (and - if you agree with the recommendations from the Android docs - better) ways to do this described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how).

Answer (score 0):

As with Richard's suggestion, your other problem is updating the TextView on the non-UI thread, so consider using a **Handler**.

Example

```
public class ShowTimer extends Activity {

    private Handler mHandler;
    private TextView timerText = null;
    private int seconds;

    private Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timerText.setText(String.valueOf(seconds++));
            mHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 1000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timer_test_xml);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        timerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimerTestId);
        timerRunnable.run();
    }
}
```