# Disappear buttons in android

Tags: android, button

In my app, I want a random button to disappear every second.

My state now is, that I've a countdown that counts from 30 seconds to 0. Every time I press a button it disappears and another one is shown. Now I want to automatizise that, that every second a random button is gone and another is shown. Here's my code until now:

```
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("F " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            System.out.println("HHH");
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ihr Highscore: " + count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
        }
    }.start();
```

The setNextButton method is called every time the user presses a button, what I want now is that is is called every second automatically:

```
public void setNextButton(Button str){

    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&& SETNEXTBUTTON");
    str.setVisibility(ImageButton.GONE);
    int zufall = (int) (Math.random()*23);
    int buttonid = str.getId(); 
    int buttonname = (int) str.getId();
    String buttonneu = "button" + zufall; 
    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&" +  getResources().getResourceEntryName(buttonid));

    int[] buttonIds = {R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4, R.id.button5, R.id.button6, R.id.button7, R.id.button8, 
            R.id.button9, R.id.button10, R.id.button11, R.id.button12, R.id.button13, R.id.button14, R.id.button15, R.id.button16 , 
            R.id.button17, R.id.button18, R.id.button19, R.id.button20, R.id.button21, R.id.button22, R.id.button23, R.id.button24 };
    Button bnew = (Button) findViewById(buttonIds[zufall]);
    //Toast.makeText(this, "$ " + getResources().getResourceEntryName(bnew.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(bnew.getId() == str.getId()){
         bnew = (Button) findViewById(buttonIds[zufall]);

    }

    bnew.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);  
    count++;

    //b.setEnabled(enabled)
}
```

How can I solve that problem in a good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great answer to this question by Dave: [android timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4598737/1182971).

Take a look at that. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Just one another short question: I've got 26 button, one is visible, there other are set to GONE. How can I get the one that is visible?

Comment: You can iterate over all buttons and see which one has its visibility set to VISIBLE

Comment: or you could save the id of the button that is visible. `private integer id_button;` create getters and setters and then `setIdButton(buttonIds[zufall]);`