# android: do some code on media player special time

Tags: android, time, media-player

I'm newbie in android programming..

I have a media player in my activity to play a sound.

I want to do some code on a special time that the media player is playing. I mean I want to do code1 during media player is in 0 to 5sec, and do code2 during 5 to 14 and do code3 during 14 to 18sec.

here's my timer code and I don't know how to run my codes on special times..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView timerTextView;
long startTime = 0;

//runs without a timer by reposting this handler at the end of the runnable
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        timerTextView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));

        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setText("start");
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button b = (Button) v;
            if (b.getText().equals("stop")) {
                timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
                b.setText("start");
            } else {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
                b.setText("stop");
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setText("start");
}

}
```

Comment: please show the code you tried

Comment: Try implementing a timer (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how) for details).

You can start the timer when you start playing the sound, and use timer's callbacks to execute the methods you need for each time on the track.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most elegant solution, especially if all your time blocks will be exactly 5 seconds apart but if you set initalTime when the media player starts, it should work. Further documentation for uptimeMillis() and other Android timer methods are [linked here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html)

```
int initialTime= SystemTimer.uptimeMillis(); 
while (mediaIsRunning){
    int currentTime=SystemTimer.uptimeMillis();
    int elapsed=currentTime-initialTime;
    if (elapsed<=5000){ // 5 seconds
        //your code 1
    }
    else if (elapsed<=10000){ //10 seconds
        //code 2
    }
    //etc ...
}
```