# How to implement timer in an android game

Tags: android, timer

In my android game, there is an arcade mode, which runs for 60 seconds. UI has to be updated every second. Is it advisable to use `CountDownTimer` to implement this because as far af i know this class does not run on separate thread ? What are other ways or best way to do this without affecting user experience ?

**EXACT CODE WHICH SOLVED MY PROBLEM**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

             // this creates timer in another thread

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        time=60;
                        while(time>0)
                        {
                            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                            long currenttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            time= (int) (60-((currenttime-starttime)/1000));
            // this updates the UI
                            timerhandler.post(new Runnable()
                            {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    tv0.setText(time + " s");
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    }

                }).start();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android timer? How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // Your code
    }
}, 60*1000));
```

Comment: does this create new thread ? how to update UI every second ?

Comment: Read the [Handler doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: Thanks I read the document and other articles now. So, this runnable will run on main thread ... right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right, assuming you created the Handler on the main thread :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Timer and TimerTask Class. Example (It gives the delay of 6 seconds. Its better to use seperate thread for this)

```
   Timer timer = new Timer("My Timer");
   TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Timer task completed .......");

        }
    };
    System.out.println("Timer task started.......");
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 6000);
```