# I need to execute a AsynckTask object 5 times with an interval of 2 minutes

Tags: java, android, timer, android-asynctask, intervals

I want to fire an event (sending a sms) every 2 minute . how can i do this . I am using AsyncTask Class to handle background task and want to use its object to execute 5 times with an interval of 2 minutes .I have seen the previous answers and try using Thread.sleep() ,Timer ,and wait but nothing worked for me . Please help guys.

Comment: Do you want them to fire at equal intervals (every 24 seconds)?  When the previous task is done?  Something else?

Comment: yes I want to fire at equal intervals .Its ok if delayed but I don't want it to execute earlier than specified interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService worker = 
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

void someMethod() {
 ⋮
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
  /* Do something… */
}
};
worker.schedule(task, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
⋮
}
```

or if you want to use timer

you can refer to this post on stackoverflow

[Android timer? How-to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how)

Comment: You should indent your code nicer so it's easier to read... you'll get more upvotes if you do.

Comment: Sorry about that... Will do so in Future. :) Thanks for Advice

Comment: Thank you @UmerKiani your code let me implement all the functionality I want to implement.

Comment: No Problem :) My Pleasure to Help My Fellow Programmers :)