# Send PUSH notification Android when fetching data is true

Tags: android, timer, notifications, push

I am trying to make a very little application. My app will fetch an url:

```
example.com/response.json
```

when this response "true" my app will send a notification message:

```
Your thing is ready! Let's see.
```

But I have no idea how to make it? Do I need a Timer or what?

I found this method:

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Message received", System.currentTimeMillis());
    // Hide the notification after its selected
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    //adding LED lights to notification
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageReceivedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("payload", payload);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Message", "New message received", pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

But how to check every 5min the response and send the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download this file using i.e. `HttpURLConnection` or `HttpClient` inside `AsyncTask` `doInBackground` method. example of fetching data:

```
HttpGet reqest = new HttpGet(yourURL);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(reqest);

String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

for parsing JSON use `JSONObject(String json)` passing `result` (and/or optionally `JSONArray` if needed)

if result matches your expectations use `Toast.makeText(...)` or Notifications ([example here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html))

Comment: Thank you, but how can I make it with Timer? Check every x minutes the response and send the notification if response is true?

Comment: if you want to poll server sequentialy then you should run your downloading stuff (`AsyncTask`) inside `Service` and then: yes, you might use timer as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how (lot to do ahead of you...) or `Handler` and its method `postDelayed(Runnable r, int delayInMillis)`