# How change viewswitcher to cahne automatically instead of tapping the image?

Tags: android, view

In my app, I want the background image to change when tapping on the image (this works perfectly), but now I was thinking of maybe having it to change automatically without tapping the image.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    ((ViewSwitcher) rootView.findViewById(R.id.switcher)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher) v;

            if (switcher.getDisplayedChild() == 0) {
                switcher.showNext();
            } else {
                switcher.showPrevious();
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

How can I make it to change automatically?

I have tried various suggestions, but nothing seems to work or it just displays the first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a handler and runnable instead and then call `handler.postdelayed(....)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [to use timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how) and after some time call function on main thread to change your image?

Comment: U cant use a timer because its on the ui thread. Its eadier to use a handler.