# How to Start Incremental Timer in Android

Tags: android, timer, handler

Before Asking Question let me tell you that this Question has been answered many time but I didn't resolve my problem.
I tried [this Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how) Answer but not really helpful.

So Problem is I am creating a Mastermind Game in android and I want to start the timer from 00:00 when user Enter the first PIN to so on until the user hit the Last PIN or When user Click on New Game Timer will Reset and will not start until User Enter the first PIN again.

So here is my Try

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        timerTextView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));

        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }
};
```

function to start or stop timer

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
    timerCheck = true;
}
```

when user hit the first PIN this code execute

```
timerCheck = true;
startTimer();
```

When user hit the Last PIN this Code Execute

```
timerCheck = false;
startTimer();
```

Nothing is Working
Please Help me To start Timer when First Condition is True and Stop Timer when Last Condition is true, in between if NewGame get Hit Timer will reset and don't start until First Pin got Hit again.
Any help will be grateful.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just Solve my Problem and here is how I Done it

Declarations

```
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
private long startTime = 0L;
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;
```

To start Timer when First PIN Enter

```
startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
```

Pause Timer When Last PIN Enters

```
timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
```

Main Runnable

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timerTextView.setText(String.format("%02d", mins) + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};
```

Its Totally Working Fine for me hope so it will work for you guys too