# How do i start a timer in java with one second interval?

Tags: java, android-studio

The timer should work non stop once i start my program with one second interval.
At the top of my MainActivity i added:

```
import java.util.Timer;
```

Then in the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

I added:

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Now i have the onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
        currentActivity = this;
        initTTS();
    }
```

How can i make that the timer will start working once i'm starting my program with interval of a second ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how

Comment: Since you mention Android, the answer is almost certainly "don't."  Use a `Handler` instead.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to import:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
```

After this you need to setup your timer like this:

```
//Declare the timer
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    //Set the schedule function and rate
    myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        //Called at every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
                                        Log.i("MainActivity", "Repeated task");
                                    }
                                },
            //set the amount of time in milliseconds before first execution
            0,
            //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
            1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start the timer with one of the schedule methods like this:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do your stuff here...
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

This will start your timer with a delay of 0 milliseconds and repeat it after 1000 milliseconds.

You should read at least the heading of the javadoc here: [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

I don't know that much about the Android platform but you have to be cautious using threading. Read about this here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

Answer (score 0):

Set the interval to 1000, because the interval in timers are based on milliseconds, so 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.

try searching for the property "Interval" in the properties tab, because i use netbeans and there is interval on side, and the command to be put on the Timer_Tick event to make sure the command is done everytime the interval happens which is every second

Comment: But how do i set the interval ? Where and how do i start the timer in the onCreate ? And how do i make the tick event if there is any ? So far i used c# and timers but never in java. I'm using android studio 1.3. For example in c# you type timer.Interval = 1000; but in java i didn't see the property Interval for the variable timer.