# Make another class to count time

Tags: android, class, time

I have a problem with create a new class to count time. This is my code:

```
Button btcheck = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btcheck);

btcheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){
        Time aa = new Time();
        aa.RunTime();                   
    }           
});
```

And

```
public class Time extends MainActivity {

    public void RunTime() {     
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);            
    }

    public Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            updatedTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);      

            stime="" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds);                            

            txttime.setText(stime + " ");
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);     
    };
}
```

However it does'nt work as I expect. Hope you help me.

Comment: Maybe you'll find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how

Comment: it doesn't show time in txttime.

Comment: Dude in your last question I mentioned you that if a class is just a normal class then don't extend it with an Activity, because to make an instance of a class which extends Activity is a very heavy ask, instead don't extend it with an activity, & if you must have to use your Activity class instance then make an static instance of your Activity class & use that as I have mentioned in your previous question.

Comment: Thank you alot. I have another question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676002/draw-bitmap-by-canvas-by-touch-screen-at-position . I hope you will help me again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use extends AsyncTask instead of MainActivity.  This way you're not creating a new activity back log and you can update your UI without conflicting with your threading.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler( );
    public long startTime;
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch( v.getId( ) ){
            case R.id.btcheck:
                this.startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                startTimer( );
                break;
        }
    }
    private void startTimer( ){
        startRunnable( );
    }

    private Runnable startRunnable( )
    {
        new Runnable( )
        {
            @Override
            public void run( )
            {
                new Time( startTime ).execute( );
                long timer = 1000;
                handler.postDelayed( startRunnable( ), timer );
            }
        };
        return null;
    }

    class Time extends AsyncTask< String, String, String >
    {
        private long startTime;
        private long updatedTime;

        public Time( long startTime )
        {
            this.startTime = startTime;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute( )
        {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( String result )
        {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground( String... param )
        {
            updatedTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis( ) - startTime;

            int secs = ( int ) ( updatedTime / 1000 );
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = ( int ) ( updatedTime % 1000 );

            publishProgress( "" + mins + ":" + String.format( "%02d", secs ) + ":" + String.format( "%03d", milliseconds ) );
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate( String... values )
        {
            txttime.setText( values[ 0 ] + " " );
        }
    }
```

Comment: it shows an error in "mHandler.postDelayed(mTimeTask,timer);" That's "The local variable mTimeTask may not have been initialized"

Comment: hi, sorry I forgot to close the method startTime( ). I have made changes to this answer

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. 1) It doesn't show time run in "txttime" and 2) it requires add @SuppressLint("NewApi") in "new Time( startTime, txttime ).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR );".

Comment: take out .executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.Serial_EXECUTOR); and replace with the usual .execute( );

Comment: After add "mTimeTask.run( );" it shows app has stopped.

Comment: If App stopped, it must have given error in LogCat, show what error you got ?