# Add new image by another class by touchscreen

Tags: android, image, class

I want to create an new image by touchscreen but it shows errors which I don't know reasons. It shows

```
The constructor ImageView(LinearLayout) is undefined
```

This is main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {   

    public LinearLayout screenlayout;

    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        final LinearLayout screenlayout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.screenlayout);

        screenlayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getY();

                        AddPicture aa = new AddPicture();
                        aa.addNewer(screenlayout, x_cord, y_cord);                      

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:                   
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;         
                   }
            });             
    }            
}
```

This is AddPicture Class:

```
public class AddPicture extends MainActivity{


    public void addNewer(LinearLayout screenlayout,int vtx,int vty) {

        ImageView i = new ImageView(screenlayout);  

        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball);
        i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        i.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));                    
        screenlayout.addView(i);        
        setContentView(screenlayout); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows "The constructor ImageView(LinearLayout) is undefined."

Comment: ImageView i = new ImageView(screenlayout); why u passing screenlayout here ? why not this : ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

Comment: I change as you said but the app has stopped after touchscreen.

Comment: share what's logcat error this time ?

Comment: Your AddPicture is just a class ? if its just a class then don't extend it with activity.. see my edit

Comment: 09-18 13:02:47.049: D/dalvikvm(5018): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1000K, 29% free 5415K/7552K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 8ms

Comment: they don't show any errors, they just have been stopped.

Comment: stopped ? elaborate i want to solve your issue

Comment: Could you copy this code to your computer and check it ? I try but i can not solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a little change in your code:

This is main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static MainActivity mInstance = null;  // new edit

    public LinearLayout screenlayout;

    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

    mInstance = this;  // new edit

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        final LinearLayout screenlayout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.screenlayout);

        screenlayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getY();

                        AddPicture aa = new AddPicture(MainActivity.this);
                        screenlayout.addView(aa.addNewer(x_cord, y_cord));  // edit                   
                        setContentView(screenlayout);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:                   
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;         
                   }
            });             
    }            
    }
```

This is AddPicture Class:

// if a simple class then do not extend with Activity

```
public class AddPicture { 

private Context mContext;

public AddPicture(Context context)
{
  this.mContext = context;
}
    public ImageView addNewer(int vtx,int vty) 
    {    
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);  // edit

        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        i.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));       

        return i;
    }
    }
```

**Edited** : Its working now

Comment: What's is YourActivityName in "ImageView i = new ImageView(YourActivityName.this);"

Comment: I removed that, pass a context or getApplicationContext

Comment: They show errors in screenlayout.addView(i);  and setContentView(screenlayout);

Comment: check where new edit is written, it should solve now

Comment: they show error at setContentView(MainActivity.mInstance.screenlayout);

Comment: Check it and if it works for you accept as an answer.

Comment: Thank you alot. I have another problem in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626109/make-another-class-to-count-time/32626494#32626494 Could you help me ?

Comment: I add some code lines to set position in screen by touch. But they don't show that position I touch the second time and more. The next Picture move far more than I touch.

LayoutParams layoutImage = (LayoutParams) i.getLayoutParams(); 

layoutImage.leftMargin=vtx; layoutImage.topMargin=vty; 

i.setLayoutParams(layoutImage);