# Count down timer showing 25:0 instead of 25:00

Tags: android, timer

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Bind(R.id.timerText)
  TextView timerText;
  @Bind(R.id.pauseButton)
  ImageButton pauseButton;
  @Bind(R.id.restartButton)
  ImageButton restartButton;
  @Bind(R.id.startButton)
  ImageButton startButton;

  private CountDownTimer mCounter;

  long millisecondsLeft;

  boolean isFirstLaunch = true;
  boolean isPaused = false;
  boolean isRunning = false;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFirstLaunch) {
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                restartButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                startButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                isFirstLaunch = false;
                setTheTimer(60 * 25 * 1000);
            } else {
                isRunning = true;
                isPaused = false;
                changeVisibility();
                setTheTimer(millisecondsLeft);
            }
        }
    });

    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCounter.cancel();
            mCounter = null;

            isRunning = false;
            isPaused = true;
            changeVisibility();
        }
    });

    restartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            restart();
        }
    });
  }

  public void changeVisibility () {

    if (isPaused) {
        startButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (isRunning) {
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        startButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }

  public void restart () {
    if (mCounter != null) {
        mCounter.cancel();
        mCounter = null;
        isRunning = true;
        isPaused = false;
        changeVisibility();
        setTheTimer(60 * 25 * 1000);
    } else {
        isRunning = true;
        isPaused = false;
        changeVisibility();
        setTheTimer(60 * 25 * 1000);
    }
  }


  private void setTheTimer(long value) {

    if (mCounter == null) {

        mCounter = new CountDownTimer(value, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                long minutes = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60;
                int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60);
                millisecondsLeft = millisUntilFinished;


                timerText.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timerText.setText("Done!");
            }
        };
        mCounter.start();
      }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is in the bottom of the code I have provided. Its some code that I found in a forum and it has a problem which I cannot solve. My timer always starts at `25:0` and then proceeds to `24:59`. This also occurs later on in the display e.g.: `23:0`. I am trying to make the seconds always display two digits instead of just a single 0.

Comment: You are using **numbers**.  But you want **strings**. `00` is not a number; therefore,`0` - translated to string is `"0"`, not `"00"`.  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: how would i implement the DecimalFormat in my code? im confused as to how to go about this

Comment: Also this answer might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4598737/61654.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
// modified from your above to highlight what you need to do
NumberFormat f = new DecimalFormat("00");
int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60);
timerText.setText(minutes + ":" + f.format(seconds)); // formatter used here
```

or as an alternative use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

```
// modified from your above to highlight what you need to do
String format = "%02d"; // two digits
timerText.setText(minutes + ":" + String.format(format, time)); // formatter used here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to zero pad your `seconds` to make sure it is always two digits:

```
timerText.setText(minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");     

System.out.println(formatter.format(2.0));
```

output willbe 2.00

this is easier for your to embed.