# Timer Android counter

Tags: android, timer

I'm trying to implement a Timer counter, but all that I see is `CountDown` and I don't want to count down time, I just want start from 00:00 and every second sum one second until 60:00, I've been trying to implement this :

1.-[Android timer? How? - Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4598737/4385913)

2.- [Chronometer](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/chronometer.php)

And they didn't help me at all.. can you guide me how to start time from 00:00 and end in 60:00?

### Answer here :

As [Usama Zafar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36219158/4329781) put his answer, I updated the code to control this `CountDownTimer` in case you'll need it...

I created

```
CountDownTimer cdtTimer;
```

Then the method I have to `startTimer()` that starts to count the time it's like this :

```
private void StartTimer(){
    final long EndTime   = 3600;
    cdtTimer = new CountDownTimer(EndTime*1000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long secondUntilFinished = (long) (millisUntilFinished/1000);
            long secondsPassed = (EndTime - secondUntilFinished);
            long minutesPassed = (long) (secondsPassed/60);
            secondsPassed = secondsPassed%60;
            tvCounterTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", minutesPassed) + ":" + String.format("%02d", secondsPassed));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tvCounterTimer.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Then wherever I want to cancel this `CountDownTimer` I simply do

```
cdtTimer.cancel();
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to go upto 60 min or 60 sec? I am not sure if 00:00 is sec:milli or min:sec

Comment: @UsamaZafar min:seconds sorry

Comment: @AndroidWannabe and this is absolute? Like you will always be going upto 60min:00sec?

Comment: nono don't worry doesn't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to implement Timer is to obviously use `CountDown` as stated on Android's official guide:

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
      }

      public void onFinish() {
          mTextField.setText("done!");
      }
 }.start();
```

But as per your requirement you don't want to count down rather you wish to count up until you reach 60min mark. How can we do it is indeed an interesting question. You can try implementing a Runnable and get system time in milliseconds on each tick using: `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

It tends to get complex right? So why not play with the CountDown Timer and make it work to our needs? How can we do it? Observe the below code:

```
 long StartTime = 0;    //Starting from 00:00
 long EndTime   = 3600;          //End at min:sec converted to seconds

 new CountDownTimer(EndTime*1000, 1000) {

      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          long secondUntilFinished = (long) (millisUntilFinished/1000);
          long secondsPassed = (EndTime - secondUntilFinished);
          long minutesPassed = (long) (secondsPassed/60);
          secondsPassed = secondsPassed%60;
          // So now at this point your time will be: minutesPassed:secondsPassed
          mytextView.setText(String.format("%02d", minutesPassed) + ":" + String.format("%02d", secondsPassed));
      }

      public void onFinish() {
          mTextField.setText("done!");
      }
 }.start();
```

The code is very easy to understand. If you still have any queries comment them and I will address them. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I want to show the progress I cna setText on onTick? I mean to show on a Textview something like 00:001 00:002 etc?...

Comment: Yes that is why I put the comment there inside onTick(). You can put it to your textView by simply using the two variables minutesPassed and secondsPassed... If you find it helpful do mark it as an answer for others to benefit from it as well.

Comment: no way to put 00:00 ? I mean with your code starts 0:0... 0:1

Comment: I mean I can't put the numbers like 00 01 02, 03?

Comment: It's possible to make this CountdownTimer don't stop I mean forget the end at 60:00 just keep counting?

Comment: Post it as a separate question as it is an answer to one specific query.

Comment: Ok I give you the link?

Comment: I faced with the problem that I have to stop the timer, and restart again, how do I save the values from the TextView and then Start agian the CountDownTimer with those values?

Comment: @AndroidWannabe Ask a sperate question and let me know when you do. Its a different question.

Comment: Posted it feel free to answer :)