# Difference when starting timer inside service and activity

Tags: java, android, service, intentservice, threadpoolexecutor

I want to have a periodically task that should be run every 30 seconds. so I'm using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` or `Timer`

```
 ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new MyTask(), 0, 30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

class MyTask implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }        
}
```

Here is `Timer`

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do something here
            }
        }, 0, 30000);
```

My question is: is there any differences if I start above code inside Service/IntentService or inside one activity. Those actions will be same or start inside service will better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android timer? How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run this task even when your app is in backgroud then You should use a `service` or if you want to run in only when your app is in front so you may use it in `activity`