# How do I delay some code in Android?

Tags: android, delay

Before anyone points to it, I have read [this answer about Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4598737/3395716) and this question builds apon it.

My code looks like this

```
Handler timerHandler =new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {//stuff that is called iteratively and needs delay before every iteration
        do some stuff;
        if(ExitCodition){
            timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
        }
        else {//call that stuff again
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    }
};
someMethodCalledOnButtonClick(){
    //do foo;
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable,500);
    //do bar;
}
```

What I need is that when `someMethodCalledOnButtonClick()` is called, the execution occurs as

> 1. foo 2.the stuff that needs delay 3. bar

What I see is that the code that needs delay is actually running independent of the later code (`bar`), so the `bar` code gets executed while the handler code is getting executed in parallel.

How do I ensure that code gets executed in proper order? All I need is to add delay in execution of every iteration of some code(without delay, I could have simply used a while loop)

Comment: You can use msg.what to distinguish different task, when your timerRunnable is finished, send a msg to handler to execute code about "do bar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handler will execute its code asynchronously, it will run in another thread. Try putting `//do bar` code inside the handler and see if you get what you want :)

```
Handler timerHandler =new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {//stuff that is called iteratively and needs delay before every iteration
        do some stuff;
        if(ExitCodition){
            timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
        }
        else {//call that stuff again
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
           //do bar; // YOUR CODE HERE
        }
    }
};
someMethodCalledOnButtonClick(){
    //do foo;
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable,500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ensure that code gets executed in proper order?

Move the logic named "bar" into the `run()` method of `timerRunnable`.

If the method name `someMethodCalledOnButtonClick` is literal — that this method is called on the main application thread in response to a button click — then you do **not** want to be blocking the main application thread in `someMethodCalledOnButtonClick()`. After all, that prevents `timerRunnable` from actually running.

Answer (score 0):

To make a delay you can use:

`SystemClock.sleep(timeInMills);`

This is just a sleep function.

Comment: Do **NOT** call `sleep()` on the main application thread, please.