# How to store time in sharedpreferences across two activities

Tags: java, android

When my users play a game, I want to lock them out of it for 30 seconds. I'm trying to use `SharedPreferences`. I'm not well acquainted with SP and not completely sure how to use it. So it should look like so

```
ifGameOver(){

//lock the game for 30 seconds 
//send users to main menu until 30seconds is over

}
```

and then at the main menu I wish to be able to see a TextView count down as the 30 seconds go down. So here I would `getLong` or something(?). Could anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save current time to `SharedPreferences` in first `Activity` class:

```
private void saveCurrentTIme() {
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("myAppPref",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putLong("GameTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
        editor.commit();
}
```

Retrieve saved time from `SharedPreferences` in second `Activity` class:

```
    private long getSavedTime() {
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("myAppPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            return sharedpreferences.getLong(Name, 0L);

     }
```

For comparing if the saved time is passed, you can create something like `Timer`.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597690/android-timer-how-to) for how to do it.