# Checking if a Java Timer is cancelled

Tags: java, timer, cancellation

Why is there no `isCancelled` method for a [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) object?

I would like to schedule a task if the Timer has not been cancelled, and run it directly (on the same thread) if it has been cancelled.

Is the only option to catch the `IllegalStateException` that might occur if the Timer already has been cancelled? (It feels wrong to catch an `IllegalStateException`).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How sure are you that you want to use `Timer`? Use [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead, which has `isShutdown` and has a slew of other benefits to boot. A general recommendation as of Java 5 has been to replace `Timer`s with `ExecutorService`s.

There's a `ScheduledExecutorService` interface specifically for scheduled executor services. Instantiate using one of the `Executors.new...` methods.

Comment: Does this mean that the `Timer` class is more or less deprecated?

Comment: Yes, you could say that. If it fits your bill, use it, but if not, move over to `ExecutorService` and never look back. On second thought, even that advice is dangerous: if you start with `Timer` and your project grows, you may regret not having started out with `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Deprecated? No, but inappropriate for a lot of tasks.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213109/java-util-timer-is-it-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I have simpler solution for those people who still wondering how to check if timer is cancelled or not. You can utilize the override function from timer class something like this

```
val timerTask = object : TimerTask() {
   override fun cancel(): Boolean {
      isCancelled = true
      return super.cancel()
   }

   override fun run() {
      isCancelled = false
      ...
   }
}
```