# Why does this code keep looping? ( concept of ActionListener)

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm a bit lost on this. So here's some code for an ActionListener:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println("hello");

      }
    };
    Timer displayTimer = new Timer(5000, listener);
    displayTimer.start();


  }
```

And it prints hello over and over... I don't quite understand. why doesn't it just print once?

thanks

Comment: What do you intend to do? Is ActionListener your custom class?

Comment: Perhaps reading the docs for `Timer` would give you a clue?

Comment: try looking for specific events like if (event==SOMETHING)

Comment: @Mr.777 - Nothing, actually , othe than learning about ActionListener and Timer.

Comment: @Adel Well, the code is working as it's written. timer is auto being called after 5 ms and the listener activates which in turn prints hello. That's why it keeps printing after ever 5 ms because you are forcing it to do that.

Comment: @Mr.777 - I think it's getting clearer now. thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a Timer and haven't called `displayTimer.setRepeats(false);`

However, I recommend using a `ExecutorService` instead of Timer. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice). There are a few things that a Timer in Java is lacking, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880202/checking-if-a-java-timer-is-cancelled) which will also help you setup an ExecutorService that will behave just like a `Timer` that you are used to.

Comment: Agree, unless you want to be sure that the repeated code is called on the Swing event thread.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Even for that, it's possible to call SwingUtilities.invokeLater, isn't it? (Even though *only* calling that might reduce the usefulness of a ExecutorService)

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation to (Timer)[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html] says, your constructor initializes the timer with both an initial delay and a between-event delay of five seconds. The timer thus executes your ActionListener every five seconds.