# Is it okay to use Thread.sleep() in a loop in Java, to do something at regular intervals?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, intervals, thread-sleep

I have read some threads that said that calling Thread.sleep() in a loop is problematic and is a serious performance issue. But in some cases it seems the most natural thing to do.

For example if I want my application to do something every **3 minutes** (lets say it's an **autosave**)

```
public void startAutosaveLoop(){
    stop = false;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!stop){
                Thread.sleep(T*1000);
                if (!stop){
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Is there a better way to doing this? Is this kind of situation problematic?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453295/timer-timertask-versus-thread-sleep-in-java

Comment: @AdriánLópez ScheduledExecutorService is preferred in most cases vs. Timer. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2213153/829571

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you sleep for a long time it won't affect the performance. If you sleep for 5ms, check some condition, go back to sleep for 5 ms etc. for 3 minutes it will have some performance cost.

If what you need is to do something every 3 minutes, it would make more sense to use a scheduler instead.

You can have a look at the [javadoc of ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for a very similar example.

Comment: is this better than the Timer class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html ? Nevermind i see now that this is for Swing

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService is preferred in most cases vs. Timer. See for example: stackoverflow.com/a/2213153/829571

Comment: @RexLakio There are 2 Timer classes: the one you found and another one in java.util.Timer which is a general purpose Timer.

Answer (score 4):

You should better use **ScheduledExecutorService** if you want to put delay. This interface supports future and/or periodic execution of task.

Pls check API doc for sample code and details:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html